# Accessing Data From Payment Getaway Array PHP

Tags: php

first sorry for my bad English and I hope you may help me since I'm new with php but all positive comment will be taken..
Okay I have a question. It's regarding to payment getaway array access. I am trying to access an array. This are APi code for Payment Getaway

```
$myfetch = mysqli_fetch_array($myquery);

 $some_data = array(
'billCode' => $myfetch['billCode'],
'billpaymentStatus' => $myfetch['status_transaksi']
 );  

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://toyyibpay.com/index.php/api/getBillTransactions');  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $some_data);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);  
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
```

This are an APi to fetch a data from an existing customer. I wanted to echo/print out some selected object. Like an example
[{"billName":"Yuran Pelajar","billDescription":"Yuran","billTo":"SOMEONE","billEmail":"example@gmail.com","billPhone":"1234455","billStatus":"1","billpaymentStatus":"3","billpaymentChannel":"FPX","billpaymentAmount":"4000.00","billpaymentInvoiceNo":"TP2109974280140220180820","billPaymentDate":"18-08-2020 20:02:14"}]

So I want to access by printing out a selected data like billpaymentAmount. Do anyone help me. Thank you for advanced for everyone who's helping. I am really appreciate it. Please give a good positive and motivated comment. Spread the love❤

Comment: That is JSON, so _decode_ it, and then access the elements of the resulting PHP object or array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toyyibpay API is returning as an Array so if you want to get billpaymentAmount from the first transaction use below code

```
$arr_transaction = json_decode($result);
echo $arr_transaction[0]->billpaymentAmount;
```

Or, if you want to get it from all transactions

```
$arr_transaction = json_decode($result);
foreach($arr_transaction as $transaction){
    echo $transaction->billpaymentAmount;
}
```